# Easy css modification to show the text only on the right of the image

Tags: html, css

How can I move the text on the right of the image ? I am trying to make it work on a mobile device and I need all the text to be on the right side, nothing on the left where the image is. Like two separate things.

```
<div>
<a href="">
<img src="image.jpg" style="">
</a>
<a href="">Here goes the title and some of the content here here content title bla bla</a>     
</div>
```

I have made a fiddle for help at
http://jsfiddle.net/nueZd/1/

Comment: Not really sure what you want to achieve, but Nadir's answer seems appropriate. However, the reminder of text that does not fit right of the image WILL be under image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nadirabid/nueZd/3/) is what you're looking for, but it works for me.

```
<div>

<a href="" style="float:left;">
<img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/HandHeld/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/s-2-49840_72x72.jpg" style="">
</a>
<a href="">Here goes the title and some of the content here here content title bla bla</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image to `float:left`, and set a `margin` on the text.
This will create a two column look, where there are no text directly beneath the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/nueZd/4/

Answer (score 1):

What you want is floating. You can add the following to the style attribute:

```
style="float:left;"
```

That way everything flows around the image on the right side. If you want to make it nice, you can also add some padding:

```
style="float:left;padding-right:10px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. The text *is* to the right of the image, but is wrapped as there is no room. Try that html in your browser. If you don't want that(wrapping) too, you can use a different div for the content and restrict it's height and width *and* give it a right float.

Also check out the W3Schools reference for [HTML5][1]. It's got a bunch of new tags to separate one type of content from another.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "dummy" solution with for small text, and two separate divs

```
<div style="float:left;align:left;height:100%">
<a href="">
<img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/HandHeld/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/s-2-49840_72x72.jpg" style="">
</a></div>
<div>
<a href="">Here goes the title and some of the content here here </a>
</div>
```

The appropriate one is make columns, like this:

```
 <div style="float:left;width:15%;height:100%;padding-bottom:100%">

    <a href="">
    <img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/HandHeld/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/s-2-49840_72x72.jpg" style="">
    </a></div>
    <div style:="width:80%;float:right;margin: 0 auto;">
    <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nam pulvinar arcu ut dolor vulputate eu dictum nisl fringilla. Nam vel nisl erat. Pellentesque vel vulputate erat. Aliquam vestibulum rhoncus mi a vulputate. Vivamus venenatis tincidunt nibh in suscipit. Fusce non magna urna. Nunc tincidunt iaculis tortor eget fringilla. Cras placerat sodales metus ac cursus. 
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec malesuada vehicula mi, ac laoreet dolor elementum nec. 
Nunc blandit, est eget tincidunt ornare, magna nunc 
pellentesque magna, ac aliquet enim metus id velit. Nunc sollicitudin, dolor eu sodales sagittis, justo odio imperdiet tellus, et tempor magna
 risus quis felis. Nam semper, metus a tempor mattis, massa ante imperdiet elit, id euismod mi nunc vitae lorem. Suspendisse adipiscing mollis leo eu posuere</a>
    </div>
```